# How can I set a duration for the fading effect time calling from any script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOutSaveGameText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    private bool hasFade = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void FadeOut()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("FadeOut");
    }

    public void FadeIn()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            FadeOut();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            FadeIn();
        }
    }

    public void FadeOutMessage(string message)
    {
        if(message == "FadeInEnded")
        {
            FadeOut();
        }
    }

    public void FadeInMessage(string message)
    {
        if(message == "FadeOutEnded")
        {
            FadeIn();
        }
    }
}
```

This is working when I press on I or O keys and also I added two events for the animations and send the events messages and it's working too. The events make it fade in/out nonstop.

Now I want to add a coroutine method that get time(duration) and it will be able to be called from any other script something like :

```
public IEnumerator StartFading(float duration)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    }
```

So if I make a reference to the FadeInOutSaveGameText script and call the method StartFading :

```
StartCoroutine(StartFading(5f));
```

Then it will fade in/out for 5 seconds or any other duration time.

I added a new IEnumerator function but not sure how to use it in the Update or how to call it from other scripts and make the fade out/in effect with time duration :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FadeInOutSaveGameText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator animator;

    private bool hasFade = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(PlayAndWaitForAnim(animator, "FadeOut"));
    }

    public void FadeOut()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("FadeOut");
    }

    public void FadeIn()
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            FadeOut();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
        {
            FadeIn();
        }
    }

    public void FadeOutMessage(string message)
    {
        if(message == "FadeInEnded")
        {
            //FadeOut();
        }
    }

    public void FadeInMessage(string message)
    {
        if(message == "FadeOutEnded")
        {
            //FadeIn();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayAndWaitForAnim(Animator targetAnim, string stateName)
    {
        targetAnim.Play(stateName);

        //Wait until we enter the current state
        while (!targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(stateName))
        {
            yield return null;
        }

        //Now, Wait until the current state is done playing
        while ((targetAnim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime) % 1 < 0.99f)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`Animator.speed`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator-speed.html) accordingly.

Make your animation clip duration exactly `1 second` - this is the easiest to calculate.

So If you want a certain duration like let's say 5 seconds all you need to do is set the `Animator.speed` to `1 / 5f`.

So in order to generalize this something like e.g.

```
public void FadeOut(float duration)
{
    animator.speed = 1f / duration;
    animator.SetTrigger("FadeOut");
    StartCoroutine(FadingRoutine(duration));
}

public void FadeIn(float duration)
{
    animator.speed = 1f / duration;
    animator.SetTrigger("FadeIn");
    StartCoroutine(FadingRoutine(duration));
}

private IEnumarator FadingRoutine(float duration)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);

    // Set animator speed to normal
    animator.speed = 1f;
}
```

---

What you describe in the comments sounds more like you actually want a continuous ping-pong fade effect.

I wouldn't use the `Animator` for that at all but a pure code based Coroutine like e.g.

```
[SerializeField][Min(0.0001f)] private float duration;

private IEnumerator PingPongFade()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // will automatically ping pong between 0 and 1
        var factor = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * duration, 1);

        //TODO apply the value to your fading (whatever that means)
        // one example could be e.g.
        var color = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        color.a = factor;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = color;
    }
}
```

This way you have to only start this routine **once** and it will automatically fade-in and out all the time.

Comment: How do I use it ? For example in the same script in the Start I'm calling FadeIn(5f); then the next line FadeOut(5f); but it's just doing the FadeIn once. Same if I'm calling it from another script/s. What I wanted is that I will call one single IEnumarator and give it time for example 5 seconds and then for a 5 seconds it will make a ping pong between fadein and fadeout. and will stop fading after 5 seconds.  For example : StartCoroutine(StartFading(5f)); and it will fade in and out for 5 seconds.

Comment: I don't want to set each fade length I want to set the overall time and in this time it will fade in out as many times as can be in the given time.  Setting the fade in out speed is good option too but I meant to make a ping pong between the fade in and out for N seconds.

Comment: It sounds like you would rather not use the `Animator` **at all** but rather use one single Coroutine which does the ping-pong fading via code ...